# qgis2web plugin overriding system locale when publishing (comma as decimal separator)

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, internationalization

I'm using qgis2web to export maps and even though in desktop client my settings are all right, when I publish (with both Leaflet or OpenLayers) the decimal separator changes from comma to point. Is there a way to fix it?

As I said, this happens only when exporting, and my concern is exclusively about how values are shown in popup fields / legend. I've considered converting values to string to overcome this, but exported files are already too big and didn't want to add any new fields (some fields need to remain as real for categorization).

I'm using QGIS 3.8.3 and qgis2web 3.12.1.

Comment: This is interesting. I'm surprised, because quite a recent change to qgis2web was to tell the exported webmaps to use your locale: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/commit/ae28a27d1228191df668f3df8d016df9066fbc2a. To clarify, this instructs *the viewer's web browser* to observe the locale. In other words, I guess you should check your web browser's localization settings. Does this help us get to the bottom of this issue?

Comment: @TomChadwin, yep, you are right. Thanks! I've just changed my browser's settings and popup values are now OK, but the ones in the legend aren't. Any clues on that?

Comment: Ah, no, the legend hasn't been fixed to use the browser's locale. I'll try to change that.